# Is it possible to set up both Crashlytics and Flurry crash analytics in the same application?

Tags: ios, flurry, crashlytics

I am currently working on a project using Crashlytics and I'd like to try Flurry's new crash analytics. I haven't been able to find any information as to whether it's possible to set up both Crashlytics and Flurry error reporting in the same application. Is it possible to run both? Would there be any drawbacks to doing so?

**EDIT:**
Here's the reply from Flurry:

> You can use only 1 crash reporting tool. So, if you have crash analytics, you cannot use any other tool. Else, crash analytics will not report crashes.

Comment: Why might it not be possible? Two different companies, two different products. The disadvantage is extra data traffic going OTA and perhaps imperceptibly slower.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using two crash analytics providers is not recommended for iOS, since Apple only allows you to set one exception handler in your app at a time.

For Android, using multiple crash analytics providers is usually okay.

http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ/CrashAnalytics#But_I_use_another_Crash_Analytics_SDK.

Comment: Ah should have checked Flurry's FAQ as well. It's odd because Crashlytics says they are compatible with others. http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92506-are-you-compatible-with-other-sdks-

Comment: So, it's possible to use Crashlytics for crash logs and Flurry for user interaction (without crash log activation)?

Comment: @RauruFerro - Yes, you can use Flurry (without Crash enabled) as well as Crashlytics together at the same time. This is the reason Flurry defaults Crash Reporting to off in iOS.

Comment: i had flurry crash reporting, then added crashlyics as the info is much better and ever since i get no crashes from flurry so @HetulPatel may be right about the handler